# KEY CHAIN export for iphone sdk (public keys and privates key and certificates,...)

Tags: iphone

I have all Key chain configuration details in my old laptop for the iphone sdk 
now i have a new labtop to make my iphone development applications 
how can i move all Key chain details to the new labtop 
how the export,import works .

Answer (score 0):

In the Organizer window of XCode, you have a section in the left pane called "Developer Profile".

Here you can *"Export Developer Profile"*. It will export all your development/distribution certificates, provisioning profiles.

On your new laptop, just *"Import Developer Profile"*, and you're done.

Comment: Will this also export the public and prvate keys in the same export ?

Comment: I guess it will. Can't say for the moment